# RestCalls using Promise in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having Rest Call code but i want to make it as a promise(using $q)what changes I need to do.
//This is my controller

```
  $scope.addCustomer=function() {
        alert("inside add Customer function");
        var customer={
            name: $scope.name,
            number: $scope.number
        };
        customerService.addCustomer(customer)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

//This is my servic

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').service('customerService', customerService);

function customerService($http, restService) {
    this.addCustomer = function(customer) {
  return restService.postRequest('customers/info', customer);
    };
```

//This is my Rest Service code

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').service('restService',restService);
function restService($http){
    //set port number and baseUrl here
    var port=3001;
    var baseUrl="http://localhost:"+port;

//generic getRequest function 
 this.postRequest=function(url,data,successCallback,failureCallback){
    return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: baseUrl+"/"+url,
             data: data
           });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

$http functions already return Promises

[show this page](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service)

Comment: what's mean "i want to make it as a promise"

Comment: do you want any others?